# macro with typed arguments exception

Tags: crystal-lang

I can use typed arguments in methods:

```
def my_method(val1, val2 : String? = nil)
  # something
end
```

but I can't do same in `macro` ([crystal play example](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3hi1))

```
macro my_macro(val1, v22 : String?)
  puts {{val1}}
  puts {{v22}}
end
```

I've got exception

```
Syntax error in eval:1: unexpected token: : (expected ',' or ')')
```

Is it possible to use predefined type in `macro`?

actualy I need something like:

```
macro my_macro(val1, val2_key val2 : String? = nil)
  # do
end
```

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

First, the types used in macros are not the same as the types in normal codes, for example, when you do `some_macro "a string"`, at compile time the type of `"a string"` is `StringLiteral`.

Second it's currently not possible to have restriction on macro's arguments..

The only thing you can do is remove the type restriction, and add an if statement at the beginning to check the type of the argument, like:

```
macro foo(arg = nil)
  {% unless arg.is_a? StringLiteral || arg.is_a? NilLiteral %}
    {% raise "arg must be a string or nil !" %}
  {% end %}
end
```

You can open an issue on the issue tracker on Github if you want this feature, I don't think there's already one.